# Why is the selection not extended when using `add()` in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with 3 input fields. The HTML looks like:

```
<label>Name </label> <input .../>
<label>Email </label> <input .../>
<label> Password </label><input .../>
```

I left the code for input tags because that's not relevant here. Now in the script part, I want to add a class 'colored' in some of my `<label>` tags that color the background of those labels with #333 (well, don't mind the goal. I know it's super easy to select my labels by simply wrapping the required labels in a class or id. But I am practising, want to select elements using more complex jQuery selectors). I tried this:

```
$('label:nth-child (1)').add ('label:nth-child (2)').addClass ('colored')
```

But it only colored the first label (label having value Name). What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the question. It is downvoted. Why?

Comment: Note that really the nth-child is "Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent." and thus ONLY the first one IS a child in this manner to which the class makes sense, the second one is an input tag.  Compare to `$('label:eq(0)').add('label:eq(2)').addClass('colored');` which selects the first and third label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding. For the purposes of the index used with `:nth-child`, it doesn't matter whether the element is a label or not. There is no `label:nth-child(2)` in your markup, because the `:nth-child(2)` element is an `input` (assuming what you've shown are at the beginning of their parent element).

You can achieve what you're trying to do via jQuery's [`.eq` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq):

```
$('label:nth-child (1)').add($('label').eq(1)).addClass('colored');
```

(unlike `:nth-child`, indexes for `.eq` are zero-based)

Or more likely:

```
$('label').eq(0).add($('label').eq(1)).addClass('colored');
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was typing as well `.eq()` will also be faster on a very large DOM.

Comment: OR this:` $('label:eq(0)').add('label:eq(2)').addClass('colored');`